# How to restrict access to main domain and allow addon domains

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess

I have domain abc.com and there is many domains under this domain as addon domains like:

- abc1.com
- abc2.com
- abc3.com

I want to restrict access to abc.com using IP, so only known IP's I have can access it. and in the same time keep abc1.com, abc2.com, abc3.com running for public.

I want to do this using .htaccess on a LAMP server I have. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is will stop access to subdomains which are the addon domains I have. I still need addon domains able to be accessed by public.